# Read cell and use text as input for VBA formula

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching for a long time now to find a simple solution for my problem but I just can't find it. My problem is that I want to reference a cell and use it as text in my VBA code.

eg:
say the cell = C104

VBA would do:

```
wb2.Sheets("Cell").Range("F8:F22").Copy
wb1.Sheets("asd").Range("B7:B21").PasteSpecial
```

This doesn't work because it isn't actually using the text from the cell. I've tried using `cell().Text` and `.value` but they don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "use it as text in my VBA code"? Do you mean you want to load it into a variable? Yyou mention cell C104 but then provide code that doens't reference that cell which is confusing

Comment: Do you want the cell Address or the cell contents? Are you trying to store it in a variable or simply post it to another cell somewhere else?

Comment: I apologise, the question was poorly written. Say I have set Location As String and then Location = C104 my first line would be     wb2.Sheets("Location").Range(....      I ended up fixing the issue by removing the "" it was a pretty silly mistake, I'm still getting my head around the syntax haha. I think in future I'll post more code with my issue to give a better idea. Thanks for looking into it for me though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple workbooks and multiple worksheets available that could potentially be the parent of *cell*. You need to reference the cell definitively and take its `.Value` or `.Text` to be used as a worksheet name without relying on *Activesheet* for a default parent.

```
dim myWS as string
myWS = wb1.Sheets("asd").Range("C104").value  '◄ this gets the value of cell. I don't know if I have referenced the correct workbook and worksheet
wb2.Sheets(myWS).Range("F8:F22").Copy _
  destination:=wb1.Sheets("asd").Range("B7")
```